# How to graph in Excel (Multiple sets)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some sets of data that look like this (all are in the same worksheet, in different rows)

```
ID (unimportant)              : (xxx) (yyy) (zzz)
Number of #'s (unimportant)   : (123) (123) (123)
Synchronization (important)   : (123) (123) (123)
Type (important)              : (abc) (abc) (abc)
```

I have multiple sets like this that have different types. I want to graph them as such:

```
Value|  X        X        X
     |  X        X
     |           X        X
     |  X                 X
     |  X        X        X
      ---------------------------------
       Type 1   Type 2   Type 3
```

Essentially what I want to do is see the spread of the values of each type (these are the controls for my data). It will be like a scatter plot, with the X coordinate being the type and the y being the value.

okay some sample data:

```
    Plate/Well ID           165-fitc-B02    166-fitc-B02
    Number of Cells     219         258
    Synchrony           0.883928571 0.783251232
    Gene                uninfected  uninfected
```

I want the graph to show the ranges of values (the min is 0 and the max is 1) to see how spread out they are. The values I'm looking at are the 'Synchrony' values, and the Gene value is the x-axis.

There are 3 types (Uninfected, 306, and CADM1). I want all three to be on one graph to see the relations. The format is the same as the sample (with the boundaries of 0 - 1)

Comment: You will need to clarify the problem for someone to help.  Your example is too abstract and the terminology in the graph doesn't match the example.  Provide some sample data and a mockup of the graph that can be related back to the data.  Leave out anything that doesn't relate to the problem.

Comment: A mockup? What do you suggest I do? As in, with photoshop (since I have no clue how to make a legitimate one)?

Comment: If the items labelled unimportant aren't relevant, leave them out.  Instead of showing format placeholders (123, abc), show sample data.  In your sample graph, use the same terminology as your data and make the sample graph reflect your sample data.  Show the sample data in the same layout as your spreadsheet so solutions can be based on your data structure.  Show all of the types/sets that relate to the graph.  Someone should be able to look at the sample data and see it in the sample graph, item for item, point for point, label for label.  Then how to get from one to the other will be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll address how to produce the graph from data in the format Excel expects.  If you need help getting the data into that format, just make that a new question.  Arrange the synchrony data in three columns, one for each type to look like this:

```
    Uninfected  306  CADM1
        123     123   123
        123     123   123
```

Select the entire table, including the headings and use Insert Chart (from the menu or right-click).  Select Line Chart.  The default chart will show connecting lines.  Right click on each line, select format data series, and set line color to "no line".  That will give you basically what you want.  You can then do some custom formatting to hide the legend, change marker shapes if you want, adjust the Y axis to a custom range with custom increments, etc.

Note that if there is extensive data, this approach may exceed the maximum number of series Excel can handle.  To stick with a line chart, you would need to do something like sort each column and pick the lowest value, highest value, and every Nth value in between to proportionally represent the data with a sample.

Another approach would be to "cheat" and use an XY scatter plot.  With XY, the X axis must be a continuous variable, not categories.  Replace the three types with the values 1, 2, and 3.  This will position all of the Y values at three points along the X axis.  The data would be structured with the X values in the first column and the Y values in the second.  You would need to populate an X value for each Y value.  With this approach, you should be able to plot a lot of data without exceeding Excel's limits, and won't need to hide lines or make markers uniform.  You can manually add a legend and X axis labels.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, but when I do as you say, the data looks a bit odd

Comment: Can you describe the ways in which you want it to look different?  Are you able to paste a screen shot into your question or do you have a service for sharing images?

Comment: the graph is funky and doesn't follow the same guidelines as I'm trying to achieve - This is what it looks like [screenshot](http://imgur.com/IdFV6pj) 

I want the graph to show each type of data in 1 column - in this graph, the points are not in a vertical line for each data set. I'm trying to find the ranges of values, so having a vertical column is a must. But thanks for your help so far. (Also if it means anything, the data is all between [0,1]

Comment: That's not what I got when I did it.  Mine looked like your mockup in the question.  Is all of your data in three columns?  Did you select "line Chart" or "XY Chart"? Did you do anything fancy, like turn the source data into a table? Did you select anything other than the three columns of data for the chart (another "dimension")?

Comment: I did exactly as you just described - here's what my excel looks like - the graph is a line graph with nothing changed. Is this the correct first step, or is something wrong with my data formatting? [screenshot](http://imgur.com/aXukQMH)

Comment: Try switching row/column (it's a button on the menu ribbon.

Comment: I clicked that and I got this - what should I do with this? I can't even see the actual graph, only the data. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/1Q2gYNx)

Comment: I have no idea how to get there.  This is nothing like what I'm getting.  I wonder if you're exceeding some chart limits.  Start with a much smaller subset--column headings and say 1/2 dozen values under each.  Then follow the steps in the answer.  If it is not in three columns, switch row/column.  Ignore or delete the lines.  See what you get and lets take it from there.

Comment: Okay, so I did what you suggested using a simple set of data (in the [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/FyjnjuM)). It works fine - how can I translate this from a simple set to a complicated set of data (A good portion of the data is in the first few screenshots if you need to look at it). Also, the graph looks a bit odd, since excel graphs the points in the rows as lines, so in each column there are 3 distinct colors that look strange. If I do this with some 50 - 60 points, will it work?

Comment: I tried it with some data and I got the correct graph after rotating - Why doesn't it work with more values? [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/QdQeIJt)

Comment: Here is a workaround that I think will work.  Try it first with your mini-example.  It will use an XY scatter chart with a "cheat".  Copy the first column of values (no heading), to a spot in Col B.  In col A, enter 1 for all of the values. Copy the second column of values and paste in col B directly below the first set.  Assign all those 2 in col A.  Copy the third column below that in B and enter 3 for all of them in col A.  So this will be two long columns.  Your three types will have X values of 1, 2, and 3, and all of your values will be Y values.  Plot as an XY chart.

Comment: While your suggestion does work, and I was planning to do this before hand, it requires a key on the side, and that just looks a bit odd. If I can't figure out how to do the line graph method, I'll use this method - Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The Line graph treats each row as a series and you probably exceeded the max Excel can handle.  You would need to do something like sort the values and plot every Nth one.  XY should handle the volume.  You can add a legend manually as a text box.  Also, won't need to deal with markers and lines.

Comment: Using your line graph method, I filtered out all of the N/A's and graphed - now it's what I want! The problem is, since each point is part of a different series, there's a lot of different symbols for each marker and it's very odd to see each graph as a bunch of symbols - is there a way to make each column its own uniform symbol and color? [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/vP9nvRp)

Comment: If you use a line graph in Excel, the markers and colors are defined by the series.  You could manually format every series to make the markers and colors alike but you couldn't define colors by category.  If you use XY, the cleanup will be much simpler--set the axis increments to integers and add a text box with the legend (still no way to color markers by X value that I can think of, but if there was some way to do conditional formatting, XY would be the most likely way to support it).